# SQL Query How to get the next row date using the temp field value?

Tags: mysql, sql, date

Here's my original query....
If you can see the date of the next_row_date '2013-01-01' which is not the last record of fld_date and the last record of the next_row_date is '2013-01-15' must be 0.

```
+-----+---+------------+---------------+
| seq | i | fld_Date   | next_row_date |
+-----+---+------------+---------------+
|  41 | 1 | 2012-10-08 | 2012-10-15    |
|  42 | 2 | 2012-10-15 | 2012-10-22    |
|  43 | 3 | 2012-10-22 | 2012-10-29    |
|  44 | 4 | 2012-10-29 | 2012-11-05    |
|  45 | 5 | 2012-11-05 | 2012-11-12    |
|  46 | 6 | 2012-11-12 | 2012-11-19    |
|  47 | 7 | 2012-11-19 | 2013-01-01    |
|  49 | 8 | 2013-01-08 | 2013-01-15    |
+-----+---+------------+---------------+
```

Here's the output I wanted. Can you help me guyz with this query?

```
+-----+---+------------+---------------+
| seq | i | fld_Date   | next_row_date |
+-----+---+------------+---------------+
|  41 | 1 | 2012-10-08 | 2012-10-15    |
|  42 | 2 | 2012-10-15 | 2012-10-22    |
|  43 | 3 | 2012-10-22 | 2012-10-29    |
|  44 | 4 | 2012-10-29 | 2012-11-05    |
|  45 | 5 | 2012-11-05 | 2012-11-12    |
|  46 | 6 | 2012-11-12 | 2012-11-19    |
|  47 | 7 | 2012-11-19 | 2013-01-08    |
|  49 | 8 | 2013-01-08 | 0             |
+-----+---+------------+---------------+
```

```
SELECT 
        db_lms.a.seq,
        (@i:=@i+1)AS i,
        db_lms.a.fld_Date,
        (db_lms.b.fld_Date)AS next_row_date
 FROM db_lms.lms_savings a, db_lms.lms_savings b, (SELECT @i:=0) ii
WHERE (db_lms.a.seq = db_lms.b.seq-1) ORDER BY db_lms.a.seq ASC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT seq, @i := @i + 1 i, fld_Date, next_date
FROM
(
  SELECT seq, @d next_date, @d := fld_Date fld_Date
    FROM lms_savings, (SELECT @d := 0) d
  ORDER BY seq DESC
) q, (SELECT @i := 0) n 
ORDER BY seq
```

Output:

```
| SEQ | I |   FLD_DATE |  NEXT_DATE |
-------------------------------------
|  41 | 1 | 2012-10-08 | 2012-10-15 |
|  42 | 2 | 2012-10-15 | 2012-10-22 |
|  43 | 3 | 2012-10-22 | 2012-10-29 |
|  44 | 4 | 2012-10-29 | 2012-11-05 |
|  45 | 5 | 2012-11-05 | 2012-11-12 |
|  46 | 6 | 2012-11-12 | 2012-11-19 |
|  47 | 7 | 2012-11-19 | 2013-01-08 |
|  49 | 8 | 2013-01-08 |          0 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea833/16)** demo.

*Note: the query will work even if you have gaps in seq numbers like in your sample data 47-49*